# Can this algorithm for 2-dimensional points be generalized to 3 dimensions?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

There is a list of 3-dimensional points $(x_1,y_1,z_1),\ldots,(x_m, y_m,z_m)$, where all coordinates are non-zero integers.

I would like to decide whether there exist positive real weights $w_x, w_y, w_z$ such that, for all $i$ in $1,\ldots,m$,
$$
(*) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ w_x x_i + w_y y_i + w_z z_i \geq 0.  
$$

---

Here is an algorithm that solves a similar problem in two dimensions (i.e., assuming $z_i=0$ for all $i$).

1. If $x_i<0$ and $y_i<0$ for some $i$, then no positive weights satisfy (*) for this $i$; return "no".
2. If $x_i>0$ and $y_i>0$ for some $i$, then all positive weights satisfy (*) for this $i$; remove this pair from the list.
3. In the remaining pairs, either $x_i>0$ and $y_i<0$, or $x_i<0$ and $y_i>0$. Denote the pairs of the former type by $A_x$ and the pairs of the latter type by $A_y$.

- For all pairs in $A_x$, (*) is equivalent to: $-y_i/x_i \leq w_x/w_y$;
- For all pairs in $A_y$, (*) is equivalent to: $-y_i/x_i \geq w_x/w_y$.

In other words, the weights $w_x,w_y$ satisfy (*) if and only if their ratio $w_x/w_y$ is in the following range:
$$
\left[
\max_{i\in A_x} (-y_i/x_i),
\ldots,
\min_{i\in A_y} (-y_i/x_i) 
\right]
$$

If this range is empty, then return "no".
Otherwise (that is, $
\max_{i\in A_x} (-y_i/x_i) \leq \min_{i\in A_y} (-y_i/x_i) 
$), return any weights $w_x,w_y$ whose ratio is in this range.

The algorithm requires O(poly(m)) arithmetic operations.

---

QUESTION: Is there an algorithm for solving the original, 3-dimensional problem, using O(poly(m)) arithmetic operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, constant-dimension LP can be solved in a strongly polynomial time.

The easiest way is just trying all vertices. A vertex is determined by $3$ half-planes (inequalities including the non-negativity constraints). Running a Gaussian elimination on a candidate set of half-planes will give a point if the half-planes are independent. Then, check the point against all inequalities.

There are at most $\binom{m + 3}{3}$ vertices, and $O(m^4)$ arithmetic operations are required.

It is possible to do it more efficiently. Randomized algorithms for [LP-type_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LP-type_problem) run in a linear time for a fixed dimension.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved in time polynomial in the length of the input.  This is an instance of linear programming, in 3 unknowns.  Linear programming can be solved in [polynomial time](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/16532/5038) when the dimension is fixed.  This doesn't answer whether or not it can be solved in O(poly(m)) arithmetic operations.

Comment: If I understand the link correctly, it says that LP is linear in the number of bits in the input ("weakly polynomial"). But the algorithm I described for the two-dimensional case is polynomial in $m$ only - the number of arithmetic operations does not depend on the number of bits ("strongly polynomial").

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi, good point!  Thank you for correcting my oversight.